# Construction of a Cartesian axes system with ruler and compass

Tags: abstract-algebra, euclidean-geometry

I've to prove that with straightedge and compass it is possible to construct a Cartesian coordinate system in $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$.

I've already proved the construction of the line perpendicular to a given line $r$, passing through a given point $P$ which may or may not lie on the line $r$.

But I'm not sure that two perpendicular lines are sufficient to build the system of Cartesian axes or if it is sufficient to add natural or rational marks on the two lines. The text has already covered the construction of the two perpendicular lines and it is probably asking for something different.

Comment: Maybe they are asking only about constructing the axes, which you say you know how to do. The points that you can construct are the constructible points, which are not all the points of the plane.

Comment: Besides two perpendicular lines, the only other thing you need to define Cartesian coordinates it to drop perpendiculars to the axes from any given point. That you know too. But you need to be given the point. If the point is non-constructible you won't be able to produce it, unless some non-constructible object is given to you.